# Enable nolock option when using flask-sqlalchemy to use sqlite database

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, samba

I have a flask app running on a centOS7 server and a sqlite database on a windows file server share.

Here are some sqlalchemy documentation that talks about what I am trying to achieve:
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/sqlite.html#uri-connections

...but it is not obvious how to achieve the same thing on flask-sqlalchemy. Right now the uri is passed as a string as an attribute of the app config

Thus far I have tried adding "?nolock=1" to the end of the uri but flask throws an error saying the file doesn't exist (maybe because it thinks "?nolock=1" is part of the path?)

Currently uri ids being used by passing it to the 'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI' attribute of the app config via a config_class:

```
config_dict = {}
config_dict['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = r"<path>/<to>/<database>.db?nolock=1"
app.config.from_object(type("DynamicServerConfig", (), config_dict))
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Based on the documentation you cited, I would expect the connection URI to be more like `"sqlite:///file:path/to/database?nolock=1&uri=true"`

Comment: Tried using that "file:" prefix. Did not work.

Answer (score 0):

So nolock also requires the uri argument and I have it on good authority from the pallets project discord that "Support for the sqlite uri arg is added in Flask-SQLAlchemy 3"

...which has not been released yet.